# Change format of images in Shiny r-Plotly Interactive Presentation

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am making a slightly unconventional presentation using `shiny` and `plotly` in r. My presentation is essentially an interactive figure with multiple points on a background image, that being up other images and text when hovered over. At the start the `background_image.png` that I upload is the background, and when I hover over one of the two points, it brings up the `image1.png` or `image2.png`. I do not include the actual images here but any should work (they are all the same dimension .png files).

My code is the following:

```
pacman::p_load(shiny,shinydashboard,plotly,base64enc,htmlwidgets,RCurl)
image_file <- "materials/background_image.png"
txt <- RCurl::base64Encode(readBin(image_file, "raw", file.info(image_file)[1, "size"]), "txt")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML("img.small-img {
          max-width: 75px;
          }")
  )),
  plotlyOutput("hoverplot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # create some local images
  if(!dir.exists("myimages")){
    dir.create("myimages")
  }
  
  myPlots <- c("materials/image2.png","materials/image3.png")
 

  
  myImgResources <- vapply(myPlots, function(x){base64enc::dataURI(file = x)}, FUN.VALUE = character(1L))
  
  dt <- data.frame(
    characters = c(0, 5),
    rank = c(0, 5),
    image_url = myImgResources
  )
  
  output$hoverplot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      dt,
      x         = ~ characters,
      y         = ~ rank,
      type      = 'scatter',
      mode      = 'markers',
      hoverinfo = 'none',
      source = "hoverplotsource",
      customdata = ~ image_url
      
    ) %>%
  # Add trace
  layout(
    images = list(
      list(
        # Add images
        source =  paste('data:image/png;base64', txt, sep=','),
        xref = "x",
        yref = "y",
        x = 0,
        y = 5,
        sizex = 5,
        sizey = 5,
        sizing = "stretch",
        opacity = 0.4,
        layer = "below"
      )
    )
  ) %>%
      event_register('plotly_hover') %>%
      event_register('plotly_unhover')
  })
  
  hover_event <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_hover", source = "hoverplotsource")
  })
  
  unhover_event <- reactive({
    event_data(event = "plotly_unhover", source = "hoverplotsource")
  })
  
  hoverplotlyProxy <- plotlyProxy("hoverplot", session)
  
   observeEvent(hover_event(), {
  new_x <- 0
  new_y <- 5

  hoverplotlyProxy %>%
    plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(
      images = list(
        list(
          source = hover_event()$customdata,
          xref = "x",
          yref = "y",
          x = new_x,
          y = new_y,
          sizex = 5,
          sizey = 5,
          opacity = 1
        )
      )
    ))

    
text_annotation <- list(
    text = "<b>Heading</span><br>Text1:<br>Text2:<br>Text3:",
    x = 4,  # Adjust the x-coordinate for the text box
    y = new_y,
    showarrow = FALSE,
    font = list(size = 15, color = "black")
  
)

hoverplotlyProxy %>%
    plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(annotations = list(text_annotation)))

})
  
  observeEvent(hover_event(), {
  new_x <- 0
  new_y <- 5

  hoverplotlyProxy %>%
    plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(
      images = list(
        list(
          source = hover_event()$customdata,
          xref = "x",
          yref = "y",
          x = new_x,
          y = new_y,
          sizex = 5,
          sizey = 5,
          opacity = 1
        )
      )
    ))

   text_annotation <- list(
    text = "<b>Heading</span><br>Text1:<br>Text2:<br>Text3:",
    x = 4,  # Adjust the x-coordinate for the text box
    y = new_y,
    showarrow = FALSE,
    font = list(size = 15, color = "black")
  )

  hoverplotlyProxy %>%
    plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(annotations = list(text_annotation)))
})
  
  observeEvent(unhover_event(), {
  hoverplotlyProxy %>%
    plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(
      images = list(
        list(
          source = paste('data:image/png;base64', txt, sep=','),
          xref = "x",
          yref = "y",
          x = 0,
          y = 5,
          sizex = 5,
          sizey = 5,
          sizing = "stretch",
          opacity = 0.4,
          layer = "below"
        )
      ),
      annotations = list()
    ))
})
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

There are a couple of problems with this code that I have not found a fix for yet. First, I am need to change the placement of the points to hover over. I don't want these points to be at the corners of the plot, rather I would like them at custom locations within the background_image. But when I change their locations, it messes up the sizing/display of the entire plot. How can I move the hover points to different locations without shifting the entire plot?

Secondly, when I hover over the points and move away, the `unhover_event` works once. However if I hover over the same point again, it becomes stuck and will not unhover and bring back the background. How can I change this so that the `unhover_event` always restores the background of the plot?

Finally, for some reason the text annotation I have set up is always the first point hovered over. So if I hover over the left point, it displays that text annotation, and even if I move to the right point, the left annotation is maintained. Vice versa for the right. How can I make the text_annotation change with the hover point?